# Dynamically choose git pager

Tags: git

I prefer to use `diff-so-fancy` as my custom git pager by setting `.gitconfig`:

```
[core]
        pager = "diff-so-fancy | less --tabs=4 -RFX"
```

But on some machine where `diff-so-fancy` is not installed, how could can I fall back to original git pager?

Comment: You can write a shell script, if diff-so-fancy exists do the `git config` command to set it, else, set it to `less`

Comment: @Hedy Could you post an example as an answer and add some explanations? Thanks!

Comment: I think the solution by @knittl is better, but I’m going to keep my shell script solution up there still

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to define a shell function which checks for existence of your executable:

```
[core]
    pager = "f() { if which diff-so-fancy>/dev/null; then pre=diff-so-fancy; else pre=cat; fi; $pre | less --tabs=4 -RFX;  }; f"
```

or a shortened version:

```
[core]
    pager = "f() { pre=$(which diff-so-fancy); ${pre:-cat} | less --tabs=4 -RFX; }; f"
```

But I wonder why you would define a pager that uses `diff-so-fancy` on a system where it is not installed? Why not set `core.pager` to something else on those systems? It's a global configuration, so you only need to set it once per system

#### EDIT

The function isn't even necessary, which allows to further shorten this to:

```
[core]
    pager = "pre=$(which diff-so-fancy); ${pre:-cat} | less --tabs=4 -RFX"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm keeping a `dotfiles` repo so every time I'm on a new machine I can pull all the configs and set up my environment quickly. One `.gitconfig` file could save lots of work.

Comment: @zingdle See my edit, I've managed to further shorten the pager definition

Comment: I use `delta`, which invokes `less` automatically. I suggest using `exec` to shorten the process tree. It also has the added benefit of allowing you to use `&& ... || ...` for the fallback, without `if else`:  
`type delta >/dev/null 2>&1 && exec delta || exec less --tabs=4 -RFX`
I always use `type` because it also finds functions, aliases, and built-ins, so it's way more robust.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
if ! command -v diff-so-fancy &> /dev/null
then
    git config —-global core.pager less
    # When it doesn’t exist
    exit
fi
git config --global core.pager "diff-so-fancy | less --tabs=4 -RFX"
exit
```

you could add the `—-version` when or something testing if it exist, I’ve actually never used it before.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to create a "wrapper" shell script which tests for the existence of various pagers and `exec`s the first one it finds. For example:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#

set -Eeuo pipefail

for name in diff-so-fancy delta less; do
  if type "${name}" 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null; then
    exec "${name}"
  fi
done
```

You could name this e.g. `pager`, make it executable and add it to your `"${PATH}"`. Then your `.gitconfig` would only need to contain:

```
[core]
  pager = pager
```